# How do I show the set of points which are connected in an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ is open?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open.  How do I show that for any $x\in U$ the set of points which can be connected to $x$ is open?

Comment: Do you mean connected by a path?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Open balls in $\mathbb R^n$ are path-connected.